# Expand NumPy Index Selection

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Let's say I have a NumPy array, `x`, and indices, `idx`:

```
x = np.ones(20)
idx = np.array([1, 2, 10, 19])
```

For these indices, if I want to set the values of `x` to zero then I can do:

```
x[idx] = 0
```

However, for each of these indices, I would like to set their `m` neighbors to zero as well (note that `m < 0` refers to the `m` neighbors to the left of the index and `m > 0` refers to the `m` neighbors to the right of the index). Naively, I could do:

```
# Note this example only works when `m > 0` 
m = 3
for i in idx:
    x[i:i+m] = 0

array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.])
```

When both `x` and `idx` are very, very long, what is the best way to avoid or improve on the performance of this for loop?

**Update**

In reality, `len(x)` is `100_000_000` and `len(idx)` is `10_000`. I need this to execute in less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what comes to mind: create a combined list of the affected indexes. Then trim it to the size of the original array. Then access the array.

```
idx1 = np.unique(np.concatenate([idx+i for i in range(m + 1)]))
idx1 = idx1[(0 <= idx1) & (idx1 < x.shape)]
x[idx1] = 0
```

Comment: Sorry, but when x and idx are very large, this is very slow. I need a solution that completes in  less than a second.

Comment: For `m=3`, my code runs on the data of your size in 2.6 ms. 7.7 ms for `m=10`, 80 ms for `m=100`. What is your value of `m`?

Comment: `m = 50`, `len(x) = 100_000_000`, and `len(idx) = 10_000`

Comment: My code runs on the synthetic data of that size in about 50 ms.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.ones(20)
idx = np.array([1, 2, 10, 19])
ranges = [np.arange(a, b+1) for a, b in zip(idx-1, idx+1)]
ranges = np.array(ranges)
ranges = np.clip(ranges, 0, len(x)-1)
x[ranges] = 0
print(x)
```

outputs

```
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.])
```

1. Using `zip` for each element of `idx` create `np.array` containing +1 and -1
2. Since there can be values over/under range of x, use `np.clip` to fit them in allowed indexes
3. Now you can just use the created array like an index

Comment: Sorry, but when `x` and `idx` are very large, this is very slow. This is likely due to the for-loop

Comment: @slaw I don't think it will be possible.

Comment: It is the list comprehension that takes over 2 sec. Numpy does not use ist comprehensions.

Comment: @DYZ oh I understand. `numpy` uses `vector operations` so, i should avoid using iteration using numpy.

Answer (score -1):

I think [numpy.linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html?highlight=linspace#numpy.linspace) is useful here. Important to set "endpoint" option = False to avoid cross-linked ranges.

```
def func1(a, idx, m):
    idx_ext = np.linspace(idx - 1 , idx + m - 1, m, endpoint = False).astype(int)
    a[idx_ext.ravel()] = 0
    return a
```

For big array execution time is not so long:

```
%timeit func1 (np.arange(100_000_000),np.tile(idx,10_000),m)
500 ms ± 8.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).